# Computing Latitude Given Quiescent Gyroscope Data

Tags: rotational-dynamics, earth

Suppose I place a gyroscope in a theoretically perfectly quiescent, closed room. Let its output be given as a vector ${\bf v} = (v_x, v_y, v_z)$ indicating rate of rotation around three orthogonal axes, where the $x$-axis points towards true north and the $z$-axis points vertically. Given the data, how could I calculate the latitude of the test location? Safe to assume Earth is a perfect sphere.

I reckon that it equals $\frac{180}{\pi}\arctan(v_z/v_x)$ should do it, because at the equator (where the latitude is zero), $v_z=0$, and as you increase the angle (move N, say) more and more of the magnitude of the rotation vector is accounted for by the $z$-axis.

Am I thinking about this correctly? Can someone help me formalize the argument?

Comment: This sounds right to me. In a frame fixed to the stars, the gyroscope stays fixed, and the rate of rotation you're describing is actually that of the earth. You're just converting into the earth's rotating frame.